# Tracking problem with EF Core 3 and Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper, ef-core-3.0, ef-core-3.1

I've an problem when using `.AttachRange()` with a list of entities mapped from DTO's. This code worked with the previous version of EF Core. There is an issue about this on GitHub - [Entity already tracked exception for entity with multiple references to same navigation property #20116](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/20116)

`.AttachRange()` throws an error:

```
The instance of entity type 'School' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'SchoolId'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.
```

I know how to fix this example case but if you have a lot of FK properties and for example a list of entities and those also have a lot of FK properties then it will be difficult.

Has anyone figured out how to do this *properly*?

```
public class School
{
    public int SchoolId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public School School { get; set; }
}



var studentsDtos = new List<StudentDTO>
                {
                    new StudentDTO
                    {
                        FirstName = "FirstName 1",
                        LastName = "LastName 1",
                        School = new SchoolDTO
                        {
                            SchoolId = 1
                        }
                    },
                    new StudentDTO
                    {
                        FirstName = "FirstName 2",
                        LastName = "LastName 2",
                        School = new SchoolDTO
                        {
                            SchoolId = 1
                        }
                    }
                };

                var students = mapper.Map<List<Student>>(studentsDtos);

                db.Students.AttachRange(students);

                db.SaveChanges();
```